# How to manage the duration of LongClick?

Tags: java, android

my problem is :

As in the Instagram's Video recording activity, I whant to perform an action(record audio) for the time that a button is pressed..

than when the button is released i whant to perform another action (the saving of the audio file and the release of the resoruces)

thaks you in advantage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OnTouchListener :

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //start recording
            }
            else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //stop recording
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```